# How can I send email based on selection - Magento contact

Tags: magento-1.9, contact-form

I want to make a functionality that based on what I select in contact form (I've add a select box in the contact form).

For example if I select a department from the select box I want that the email goes to that department and not to the central email for contact form.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

You have to override postAction():

**app/etc/modules/SeStro_Contacts.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <SeStro_Contacts>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </SeStro_Contacts>
    </modules>
</config>
```

**app/code/local/SeStro/Contacts/etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<config>
    <SeStro_Contacts>
        <modules>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </modules>
    </SeStro_Contacts>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <contacts>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <SeStro_Contacts before="Mage_Contacts">SeStro_Contacts</SeStro_Contacts>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </contacts>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

**app/code/local/SeStro/Contacts/controllers/IndexController.php**

```
<?php
require_once Mage::getModuleDir('controllers', 'Mage_Contacts').DS.'IndexController.php';

class SeStro_Contacts_IndexController
    extends Mage_Contacts_IndexController
{
    public function postAction()
    {
        $post = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
        if ( $post ) {
            $translate = Mage::getSingleton('core/translate');
            /* @var $translate Mage_Core_Model_Translate */
            $translate->setTranslateInline(false);
            try {
                $postObject = new Varien_Object();
                $postObject->setData($post);

                $error = false;

                if (!Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['name']) , 'NotEmpty')) {
                    $error = true;
                }

                if (!Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['comment']) , 'NotEmpty')) {
                    $error = true;
                }

                if (!Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['email']), 'EmailAddress')) {
                    $error = true;
                }

                if (Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['hideit']), 'NotEmpty')) {
                    $error = true;
                }

                if ($error) {
                    throw new Exception();
                }

                $selectedEmail = $post['name_of_select_list']; // you have to change key of $post array
                switch($selectedEmail) {
                    case 1:
                        $email = Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email_ident_general_email');
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        $email = Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email_ident_sales_email');
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        $email = Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email_ident_support_email');
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        $email = Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email_ident_custom1_email');
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        $email = Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email_ident_custom2_email');
                        break;
                    default:
                        $email = Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email_ident_general_email');
                }

                $mailTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template');
                /* @var $mailTemplate Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template */
                $mailTemplate->setDesignConfig(array('area' => 'frontend'))
                    ->setReplyTo($post['email'])
                    ->sendTransactional(
                        Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE),
                        Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_SENDER),
                        $email,
                        null,
                        array('data' => $postObject)
                    );

                if (!$mailTemplate->getSentSuccess()) {
                    throw new Exception();
                }

                $translate->setTranslateInline(true);

                Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Your inquiry was submitted and will be responded to as soon as possible. Thank you for contacting us.'));
                $this->_redirect('*/*/');

                return;
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                $translate->setTranslateInline(true);

                Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->addError(Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Unable to submit your request. Please, try again later'));
                $this->_redirect('*/*/');
                return;
            }

        } else {
            $this->_redirect('*/*/');
        }
    }
}
```